# Advanced Custom Forms PHP formatting for do_shortcode

Tags: php, shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

Hi i am trying to build a simple wordpress template template and want to introduce a pdf viewer into the page that pull's it file from an ACF field I am pulling my hair out with the syntax on the following do_shortcode call

```
PHP
<?php echo do_shortcode("[tnc-pdf-viewer-iframe file=".get_field('document_link')." width="900px" height="700px" download="false" print="false" fullscreen="true" share="true" zoom="true" open="true" pagenav="true" logo="true" find="true" current_view="true" rotate="true" handtool="true" doc_prop="true" toggle_menu="true" toggle_left="true" scroll="true" spread="true" language="en-US" page="" default_zoom="" pagemode=“”]");?php>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are echoing the shortcode, I think you still need to echo the ACF field inside the string of the do_shortcode function. 
Change your ACF field return function for the_field() :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[tnc-pdf-viewer-iframe file=".the_field('document_link')." width="900px" height="700px" download="false" print="false" fullscreen="true" share="true" zoom="true" open="true" pagenav="true" logo="true" find="true" current_view="true" rotate="true" handtool="true" doc_prop="true" toggle_menu="true" toggle_left="true" scroll="true" spread="true" language="en-US" page="" default_zoom="" pagemode=“”]");?php>
```